# Laravel Cookies

Tags: laravel

Как в Laravel задать куки? Пытаюсь сделать вот так, но куки не записываются.
Controller

```
use Cookie;
public function add($y, $x)
    {
        Cookie::queue('products', 'test');
    }
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('cart/add/{y}/{x}', 'Api\CartController@add');
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies) это можно сделать так:

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie(
    'name', 'value', $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly
);
```

или так:

```
$cookie = cookie('name', 'value', $minutes);
return response('Hello World')->cookie($cookie);
```